# UNC Argument in bash scipt

Tags: bash, shell-script, quoting, arguments

I want to create a bash script with a "pure" UNC (i.e. I do not want to escape the backslashes literally) as an argument, i.e. something like:

```
./foo \\my\share\is\here
```

However, as is natural, the above script reads:

> \myshareishere

Can I somehow read the exact UNC as an argument and store it in a variable?

Comment: Git Bash allows you to use `//my/share/is/here` style UNC paths. You can even `cd` there (something a DOS prompt wouldn't let you). Might work with Cygwin too, but I haven't tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use single quotes:

```
[root@xxx601 ~]# ./stack \\my\share\is\here
You Gave Me: \myshareishere
[root@xxx601 ~]# ./stack '\\my\share\is\here'
You Gave Me: \\my\share\is\here
```

Comment: In other words there is no way to avoid quotes, isn't it?

Comment: Not really. It's the shell you're typing into that's interpreting the backslashes as escape characters so you can't really change the script you're running to get around that (it's already fubared by the time your script gets it).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run the command `./foo` with the argument `\\my\share\is\here` in a shell script, then you need to use some form of [quoting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Quoting), because the backslash character has a special meaning of the shell. The simplest form of quoting is to put single quotes around the argument: everything between a pair of single quotes is treated literally, the only character you can't include this way is the single quote character itself.

```
./foo '\\my\share\is\here'
```

If your script is `foo` and you want to run it with the argument `\\my\share\is\here` on the command line, then there too you need to use quoting (the command line is a shell).

If you type `./foo \\my\share\is\here`, then `foo` has no way to know what you typed. It's the shell that runs `foo` that parses the command line, and decides that the space after `./foo` is a word separator, and that the first word is a command name to execute and the second word is an argument, and that character sequences of the form backslash+something stand for the character something. It's just the same phenomenon as if you write `foo ; bar`: this is a shell command to run `foo`, then `bar`; it doesn't pass the string `; bar` to `foo`. Similarly, `./foo \\my\share\is\here` runs `./foo` with the argument `\myshareishere`. If you want to run `./foo` with the argument `\\my\share\is\here`, you need to write what you mean, for example  `./foo '\\my\share\is\here'` (or `./foo \\\\my\\share\\is\\here` or `./foo '\'"\\m"y\\share'\is\'"here"""` or any other variation).